# How to get a value from a form control

Tags: axapta, x++

My situation is very simple. Please guide me. (x++/AX)
I have a form, which includes a IntEdit control. User can type-in integer value in this control.

Meanwhile, I have another class, which has a method. This method needs to get the integer value from IntEdit control.

My question is:
How to get the integer value of that form in this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation typically requires some type of relation between the class and the form.

The class could be a `RunBase` class and the field could be in a form instantiated in the `dialog` method. Have a look on the implementation of `Tutorial_RunbaseForm` class and form to cover the this case.

Beware, in most cases it is not needed to create a form, search for method name `dialog` in classes to other ways to prompt for input.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Now I try to code as belows. Please help me check if this action is practible.
=======================
Int i = MyClassName::find().myTableFieldName;

Comment: I think my code is correct and I test it on my side. Thanks for your help.